# Include a "Research Highlights" section between the abstract and keywords?

Tags: journal-publishing

Several journals are now requiring research highlights to be included between the abstract and keywords section of journal articles. I'm not sure how to include them. Below is the section of my LaTeX document. What should I use for research highlights? (The sample .tex file provided by the journal does not include research highlights, so I cannot simply refer to the journal's documentation.)

```
\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

%Research highlights needs to go here, but how?

\keywords{one, two, three}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you explain what are "Research Highlights" ?

Comment: It might help to specify, which journals you mean. I just checked my recent publication with Elsevier. They obviously do not include the Research Highlights in the PDF, but only list them at their webpage. Consequently, there is no command in the elsarticle template to include them. They are only entered in some online form upon submission.

Comment: This depends entirely on the document class you're using.  But if the journal is requiring them, shouldn't their sample tex file show how to include them?  If it doesn't, I would email the journal and ask what they want.  A good journal would make it easy to do with their document class.

Comment: @engineer Now there's a dedicated command for both highlights and graphical abstract in the recent update of elsarticle.

Answer (score 5):

Try this...

```
\begin{abstract}
Text of abstract...
\section*{Highlights}
\begin{itemize}
   \item blablabla.
   \item blablabla.
   \item blablabla.
\end{itemize}
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
word1 \sep word2 \sep word3
\end{keyword}
```

Comment: Tough crowd sometimes. Itemization is a pretty common way to "hit the highlights." Nothing (yet) in the OP about paragraphs.